# When a gas mixture of oxygen (99%) and nitrogen (1%) is released from a container of known volume into another evacuated container

Tags: thermodynamics

When a gas mixture of oxygen (99%) and nitrogen (1%) is released from a container of known volume into another evacuated container with a different volume, does the concentration gradient of the remainder of that mixture in the first container change?

Answer (score 0):

Gases are perfectly miscible and oxygen and nitrogen have densities that are very, very close together, so the concentration gradient in the first container is truly insignificant.

Piping some of that gas over into another container doesn't change that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. By releasing some of that mixture the partial pressures (let's assume they're not equal) change because both gases move at different velocities, so their mole fractions change, even if it's only a little?

Comment: If you allow the gas to stand in it's container an imperceptible separation would take place, in the sense that the lighter gas would *tend* to rise to the top. Bulk movement (flow) would not perceptively change that. In a centrifuge (or rather a whole battery of them) a little change cold be observed in mole fractions.

Comment: How would you try to determine this binary change? By using mass transfer theory, i.e. flux equations (combining Fick's Law with the Onsager Relations, the entropy production equation, and the linear laws)? I have been reading all about mass transfer, but haven't found a suitable worked out example just yet. Or would you solve this differently? 
I tried solving this problem by combining the difference form and the rate of change form of the mass and energy balance equations of this two component system on molar basis, but got nowhere.

Comment: @user3621798: I would start by looking at the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. The distribution of molecular velocities depends on molar mass.

Comment: You mean rewriting the molar mass and energy balance equations in terms of the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user3621798: have a look at this: https://www.princeton.edu/~aglaser/2008aglaser_sgsvol16.pdf. From that reasoning something can be gleaned, I think.